# Create polyhedron for given matrix A and vector b

Tags: combinatorics, sage, polyhedra

```
P(A,b)={x∣ A.x ≤ b}
```

I have to create a polyhedron with this inputs

but in sage inequalities like this `A.x + b >= 0` , how to convert

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
sage: A = matrix(2,2,[1,23,31,4])
sage: b = vector([55,66])
sage: Polyhedron(ieqs=(-A).augment(b)).inequalities_list()
[[-1, -23, 55], [-31, -4, 66]]
```